# Reading XML with jQuery and SEO

Tags: jquery, xml, seo

I have used jQuery to parse an XML file to populate certain pages in my website and it works great.  I have since discovered that the pages are not showing up in search engines.

I am assuming this is because jQuery is doing all the work on the client side rather than server side?  Is there any way to fix this without having to use PHP or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Javascript run by search engine spiders is minimal, if any at all. You should never depend on populating your content on the client-side like that, but rather it should be done on the server.